# Contenteditable doesn't work with table in Opera

Tags: html, opera, contenteditable

Do you know, why `contenteditable=true`, doesn't work in Opera?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td contenteditable="true">This is a paragraph. It is editable.</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_contenteditable

Opera version: 12.16, build 1860 
Platform: Mac OS 10.9.1

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable: "...implementations vary significantly on how certain elements can be edited.", and "In Internet Explorer contenteditable cannot be applied to the `TABLE`, `COL`, `COLGROUP`, `TBODY`, `TD`, `TFOOT`, `TH`, `THEAD`, and `TR` elements directly..."

Answer (score 3):

The support is currently rather flaky. Browsers have not completely caught up yet.

The easiest solution until it is fully supported is to place a `DIV` or `SPAN` inside the cell and make that one editable. See the "Remarks" section on [the related MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533690(v=vs.85).aspx).

You should also add a `min-height` style rule. If you leave that out it will shrink to 0px if there is no content in the cell, and the user will have a hard time clicking on it to grab the focus. Tab stops should work fine though.

Here's something I used for debugging:

```
TD > DIV[contenteditable="true"] {
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    min-height: 1em;
}
```

Your DOM structure would then look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <div contenteditable="true">This is a paragraph. It is editable.</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```